# online editors for various file types, doc, dwg, image

Tags: php, ms-word, editing, autocad

I have a media archive with various file types on my server.  If a user wants to update that file, he has to download the file to his local machine, edit it with his desktop software (Word, AutoCAD, etc), then reupload the file.  It's kind of a pain for my users.  Has anybody run into this problem and solved it in the past.  I'm aware of using samba, but that's not *exactly* what i want.  Are there any tools out there that can help me edit files that are on a server?  I'm thinking kind of like a Google Docs  kind of thing, your file actually sits somewhere in Googleland, but you can access and edit it in your browser.  The files I would want to edit are:

- `.doc`
- `.dwg` (AutoCAD)
- `.jpg` (is there a good image editing client out there?)

My language of choice is PHP, but I can do anything really if I have to.

The bottom line is I have a doc, for example, on my server in some directory. I want the user to edit the content of that doc and have it be replaced in place with as minimal hassle on the user as possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, I doubt that there is one coherent solution for editing a variety of file types

Comment: yes SimpleCoder, I realize that a potential solution for docs will have nothing to do with a solution for dwg. I consider them separate problems. So I guess my question is "can you help me solve this problem for any single file format?"

Comment: Since you're looking at a variety of file types, would it be sufficient if the user could edit the files in software installed on their machine but keep the files on the server instead? I think you may be hard pressed to find anything like a Google docs sort of thing that could be easily integrated into a website.. And for free, if it even exists.. perhaps some kind of FTP solution is your best bet? are you looking to have the software as part of your website or maybe link to other services? just a thought. Oh.. and +1 for the term 'Googleland' - i'm using that phrase from now on. XD

Comment: Partack, yes, this doesn't have to be a http thing persay, i'm open to other services, but the problem with samba or ftp is that i'd be relying on the user to put the correct file in the correct spot. also i lose a ton of control that way, for example the user could delete a file via ftp that i don't want him to touch.  I really don't care how it's edited, i just need the file edited

Answer (score 2):

- https://www.autocadws.com/ (CAD)
- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dcjeclnkejmbepoibfnamioojinoopln (CAD)
- https://docs.google.com (documents)
- http://www.aviary.com/ (Images)

Online image editors are the easiest and most plentiful to find. You can roll your own half-baked version or use one of the API's like Aviary.

Google documents is very nice for the business side of things (Excel, Email, Word documents with multiple people working at a time).

Comment: All great suggestions. But was the OP asking for integratable software for their own site or external services? or both? .. I'm unclear on how they need to implement it..  as going to external sites with files stored on the OP's media server would be the same as downloading the files to the users pc and then editing them.. almost.

Comment: Yes, Partack is correct. I already have my server with many many files on it. I want them edited on my server. If there are third party tools that will take a file from my server, edit it and then replace it back on my server, that would be acceptable. I don't think google docs will send the doc back to my server.

Comment: I posted these links because to my knowledge google doc's and Aviary have API's you can use to work on files on your own server so no-one has to upload or download anything.